# I want to add a icon to a tab to close it in angular, ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a set of tabs with a plus bootstrap icon to add a tab dinamically,

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller("TabsParentController", function ($scope) { 
   var setAllInactive = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
        workspace.active = false;
    });
   };

    var addNewWorkspace = function() {
    var id = $scope.workspaces.length + 1;
    $scope.workspaces.push({
        id: id,
        name: "Workspace " + id,
        active: true
    });
   };

   $scope.workspaces =
  [
    { id: 1, name: "Workspace 1", active:true  },
    { id: 2, name: "Workspace 2", active:false }
  ];

  $scope.addWorkspace = function () {
    setAllInactive();
    addNewWorkspace();
  };       

  });

  app.controller ("TabsChildController", function($scope, $log){

  });
```

here's the plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/iXYHt8sqEzk1R5J4eZxm?p=preview, what i try to achieve is to add a close icon to every tab so that when u click that icon the tab closes like this plunkr : http://jsfiddle.net/alfrescian/ZE9cE/. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add the icon, you are going to need the `<tab-heading>` tag.  Once you add that in, it works fine (I only copied the first few lines...the other lines within the tab are still needed).

```
<tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" active=workspace.active>
    <tab-heading>
        {{workspace.name}} <a ng-click="removeTab($index)" href=''><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
    </tab-heading>
```

You will also need to add the removeTab method.  All you will need to do is splice the object from your JSON.  The example jsfiddle includes a remove function that shows you how.

Comment: thanks for the info, when i got this working I'll put it here.

Comment: i had to put an index to the code to get it work,                                                                                  $scope.removeWorkspace = function(item) {

      var index = $scope.workspaces.indexOf(item);
      $scope.workspaces.splice(index, 1);

                        };                                                                                    looking for info on the web i found some on the angular docs and got me to the right way, here a updated plunker how to add an index: http://plnkr.co/edit/IRNonRk5aP366iCGM6UN?p=preview

Comment: Yes, if you are passing the item itself and not the index of the item, you need to find the index.  In my example, it would pass the index of the item into the remove function.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML markup**

```
 <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsParentController">
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
             active=workspace.active >
            <tab-heading>
              {{workspace.name}}
                <a ng-click="removeWorkspace(workspace.id)"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i></a>
            </tab-heading>
            <div ng-controller="TabsChildController">
                <div>
                    {{$parent.workspace.id}} : {{ $parent.workspace.name}}
                </div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="workspace.name"/>
            </div>     
        </tab>
        <tab select="addWorkspace()">
            <tab-heading>
                <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
            </tab-heading>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("TabsParentController", function ($scope) {

    var setAllInactive = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
            workspace.active = false;
        });
    };

    var addNewWorkspace = function() {
        var id = $scope.workspaces.length + 1;
        $scope.workspaces.push({
            id: id,
            name: "Workspace " + id,
            active: true
        });
    };

    $scope.workspaces =
    [
        { id: 1, name: "Workspace 1", active:true  },
        { id: 2, name: "Workspace 2", active:false }
    ];

    $scope.addWorkspace = function () {
        setAllInactive();
        addNewWorkspace();
    };      

    $scope.removeWorkspace = function(item) {
       $scope.workspaces.splice(item, 1);

    };

});

app.controller ("TabsChildController", function($scope, $log){

});
```

Comment: there is some issues , when you try to remove the actual tab you can't , the left tab is erased instead, but you put me on the right track, ill work on it.thanks you have helped a lot.